# Clonezilla Backup software freezes on boot

Tags: backup

I can get as far as the GRUB menu. After that using any of the menu options I get a gray screen saying "Loading please wait..." and a blinking cursor. The cursor disappears after about 1 second and everything freezes up.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a bad Image unable to load the kernel or the kernel not being compatible with the CPU architecture on the system.